# Comparing n image matrices

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a classification task on a number of gray-scale images (m classes and n images in each class). Before showing my classification results, I want to show that the intra-class variation between the images is high and the inter-class variation is low. This is apparent when we see the images but how do we formulate it into a mathematical result? There was a question on comparing two matrices on [Comparing two matrices in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938260/comparing-two-matrices-in-matlab) but I want to do it on n matrices of a class.[image]

---

[image]

Could there be a criteria (class dependent) which could tell us that an image is x distance off the class average?

Comment: I get the general idea of what you're looking for, but showing a few images would make a world of difference.  Some measurements would work great to show what you want for certain kinds of images; others would be awful.

Comment: The images are of human gestures. They have a lot of variations in rotation, scale and deformable silhouettes.

Comment: I have added two images that belong to the same class.