# Matlab - Compare vectors with setdiff while ignoring precision below eps

Tags: matlab, matrix, floating-point, comparison, precision

Given two vectors containing numerical values, say for example

```
a=1.:0.1:2.;
b=a+0.1;
```

I would like to select only the differing values. For this `Matlab` provides the function [setdiff](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html). In the above example it is obvious that `setdiff(a,b)` should return `1.` and `setdiff(b,a)` gives `2.1`. However, due to computational precision (see the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918539/matlab-precision-simple-subtraction-is-not-zero) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab)) the result differs. I get

```
>> setdiff(a,b)
   ans = 
      1.0000 1.2000 1.4000 1.7000 1.9000
```

`Matlab` provides a function which returns a lower limit to this precision error, [eps](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). This allows us to estimate a tolerance like `tol = 100*eps;`

My question now, is there an intelligent and efficient way to select only those values  whose difference is below `tol`? Or said differently: How do I write my own version of `setdiff`, returning both values and indexes, which includes a tolerance limit?

I don't like the way it is answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938260/comparing-two-matrices-in-matlab), since matlab already provides part of the required functionality.

Comment: I am not sure if this elegant or "approved" by any source, but you can use a tolerance, `tol` of a very small number or which could be a multiple of `eps` and get the exclusive values using `bsxfun` like so - `setdiff_BA = b(~any(abs(bsxfun(@minus,b,a'))<tol,1))`. And interchange `a` and `b` for `setdiff_AB`.

Comment: @Schorsch You are right on this. We definitely need a value `tol > eps`.

Comment: I think I found a sweeter solution to this. Since MATLAB performs subtractions with `setdiff`, you can use `eps` directly here as the `tolerance` with `<=`, like so - `setdiff_BA = b(~any(abs(bsxfun(@minus,b,a'))<=eps,1))`. Thus, you don't have to worry about `tol`. If MATLAB were doing multiplication or division, the tolerance would not be `eps` and would change accordingly. It's sort of a logical estimate without any reference though.

Comment: @Jost You could just round both of your matrices off to `tol` (i.e. `a_rounded = round(a/tol)*tol`) and then call `setdiff` on the rounded matrices

Comment: @Divakar I have updated the question. Also, I like your solution. Please formulate an answer reflecting the small changes. Remember that the answer should be valid for matrices as well.

Comment: @Jost Your question is specific to vectors because `setdiff` works on vectors only. If you want to extend the solution to 2D matrices too, then maybe you could suggest some function that operates on those?

Comment: @Dan Good idea, but the `a_rounded` is again limited by numerical precision, so this does not work as expected.

Comment: @Jost but they will be limited in the same way so the precision shouldn't be a problem. Have you tested it on your numbers?

Comment: @Dan, yes for my numbers it's not working, unfortunately.

Comment: @Divakar Your method works for me. And you are right, I was fooled by the description in the matlab documentation, there is no "real" matrix comparison here. I'll replace the "matrixes" by "vectors" in my question.

Comment: @Jost Posting the solution in a bit with some comments for the code.

Comment: @Jost it does work on your example numbers though... so how do your actual numbers differ to stop the rounding from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction and custom function

In a general case with floating point precision issues, one would be advised to use a tolerance value for comparisons against suspected zero values and that tolerance must be a very small value. A little robust method would use a tolerance that uses `eps` in it. Now, since MATLAB basically performs subtractions with `setdiff`, you can use `eps` directly here by comparing for lesser than or equal to it to find `zeros`.

This forms the basis of a modified `setdiff for floating point numbers` shown here -

```
function [C,IA] = setdiff_fp(A,B)
%//SETDIFF_FP Set difference for floating point numbers.
%//   C = SETDIFF_FP(A,B) for vectors A and B, returns the values in A that 
%//   are not in B with no repetitions. C will be sorted.
%//
%//   [C,IA] = SETDIFF_FP(A,B) also returns an index vector IA such that
%//   C = A(IA). If there are repeated values in A that are not in B, then
%//   the index of the first occurrence of each repeated value is returned.

%// Get 2D matrix of absolute difference between each element of A against 
%// each element of B
abs_diff_mat = abs(bsxfun(@minus,A,B.')); %//'

%// Compare each element against eps to "negate" the floating point
%// precision issues. Thus, we have a binary array of true comparisons.
abs_diff_mat_epscmp = abs_diff_mat<=eps;

%// Find indices of A that are exclusive to it
A_ind = ~any(abs_diff_mat_epscmp,1);

%// Get unique(to account for no repetitions and being sorted) exclusive 
%// A elements for the final output alongwith the indices
[C,IA] = intersect(A,unique(A(A_ind)));

return;
```

## Example runs

**Case1 (With integers)**

This will verify that `setdiff_fp` works with integer arrays just the way `setdiff` does.

```
A = [2 5];
B = [9 8 8 1 2 1 1 5];
[C_setdiff,IA_setdiff] = setdiff(B,A)
[C_setdiff_fp,IA_setdiff_fp] = setdiff_fp(B,A)
```

**Output**

```
A =
     2     5
B =
     9     8     8     1     2     1     1     5
C_setdiff =
     1     8     9
IA_setdiff =
     4
     2
     1
C_setdiff_fp =
     1     8     9
IA_setdiff_fp =
     4
     2
     1
```

**Case2 (With floating point numbers)**

This is to show that `setdiff_fp` produces the correct results, while `setdiff` doesn't. Additionally, this will also test out the output indices.

```
A=1.:0.1:1.5
B=[A+0.1 5.5 5.5 2.6]
[C_setdiff,IA_setdiff] = setdiff(B,A)
[C_setdiff_fp,IA_setdiff_fp] = setdiff_fp(B,A)
```

**Output**

```
A =
    1.0000    1.1000    1.2000    1.3000    1.4000    1.5000
B =
    1.1000    1.2000    1.3000    1.4000    1.5000    1.6000    5.5000    5.5000    2.6000
C_setdiff =
    1.2000    1.4000    1.6000    2.6000    5.5000
IA_setdiff =
     2
     4
     6
     9
     7
C_setdiff_fp =
    1.6000    2.6000    5.5000
IA_setdiff_fp =
     6
     9
     7
```

Comment: @Jost You should not make substantial code changes to someone else's answer. Either comment with the suggestion for the OP to make themselves, or post your own answer (citing the original).

Comment: @Jost I got your idea what you are trying to do. I need to make few more edits with it and will incorporate what you had in mind.

Comment: @Divakar Be careful with the `'`! It gives the complex conjugate transpose, not the transposed matrix, as does `.'`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Understood, thanks for the hint. But Divakar apparently got to see my changes, which made it a lot easier for him to understand what I meant. Is there an 'official' way of achieving this functionality?

Comment: @Jost I think what you did was okay. I was still reviewing it though. Main thing is the idea came through to me. I think it would be better to not get into `tol` inside the function, otherwise we would be needed to guide users on what must be `tol`, which circles back to the user being needed to handle FP issues.

Comment: @Jost Check out the edits! Phew, that part of adding the indices was some work!! Hope this works out for you.

Comment: @Jost I was curious if the indices finding part looked good too. If the solution has met the expectations of the question, consider accepting it, so that people with similar issues could find it easily, as accepted solutions stay at the top, maybe you know about that.

Answer (score 0):

For Tolerance of 1 epsilon This should work:

```
a=1.0:0.1:2.0;
b=a+0.1;
b=[b b-eps b+eps];
c=setdiff(a,b)
```

The idea is to expand b to include also its closest values.